# Is it possible to convert a raw file to text in python?

Tags: python-2.7, text, binary, binaryfiles

I have generated a raw file from ".wav" file using

```
sox out/out/output$num.mp3 -c 1 -r 16000 out/raw/poke$num.raw
```

This has generated a raw file which looks like this:
ÿÿ\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00ÿÿÿÿ\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00ÿÿ\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00ÿÿ\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00ÿÿÿÿÿÿ\00\00\00\00ÿÿ\00\00\00ÿÿ\0

Is it even possible to convert this into a text file in python?

Comment: Could you please clarify what text you want or expect?  For me, an .mp3 file doesn't have an obvious "text" equivalent - are you asking about speech recognition, retrieving song lyrics, a file dump of sample values, or what?

Comment: @Spike0xff Yes, I am asking about speech recognition. The "wav" file has a number uttered in it. (e.g "one") I want to retrieve that from my raw file. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: OK, those are kind of important facts that are not mentioned anywhere in your question: It's important when asking how to process data, to describe the data!  For example, are you processing ONE file containing just the spoken word "one"? Or do you actually have a set of files and if so, do they all contain the word "one" or - what do they contain? Are all the recordings spoken by one speaker, or does the speaker vary? Is the quality good or poor?  What operating system - or does this also need to be portable?